# How to install Node.js 12 on CentOS 8?

Tags: yum, node.js, centos8, rhel8, dnf

I tried the following [this post](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/15/rhel8-introducing-appstreams/) which states

> Application Streams are typically named for the version of the software that is included, e.g. nodejs:8 or  nodejs:10 [...]

... but as you can see below: It's not working.

```
$ dnf module list nodejs
    Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:21 ago on Thu 02 Apr 2020 09:23:13 PM CEST.
    CentOS-8 - AppStream
    Name               Stream             Profiles                                          Summary
    nodejs             10 [d]             common [d], development, minimal, s2i             Javascript runtime
    nodejs             12                 common, development, minimal, s2i                 Javascript runtime
    Hint: [d]efault, [e]nabled, [x]disabled, [i]nstalled

$ sudo dnf module install nodejs:12
    Last metadata expiration check: 0:51:35 ago on Thu 02 Apr 2020 08:33:41 PM CEST.
    Error: Problems in request:
    missing groups or modules: nodejs:12
```

How can I specify which application stream aka version I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yum module enable nodejs:12
yum install @nodejs:12/common
```

Taken from here: https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/managing-userspace-components/assembly_installing-rhel-8-content/

Comment: It works with a small change to your answer! I submitted an edit.